# cancelAnimationFrame or clearTimeout

Tags: javascript

It seems that I lost myself between cancelAnimationFrame and clearTimeout. Don't know how to stop Snake game. Here is snippet of my code that start animation:

```
window.addEventListener( "load", function gameLoop() {
  globalTimer = setTimeout( function() {
    snakeObj.update();
    requestAnimationFrame( gameLoop );
  }, 100 );
 });
```

in this way I tried to stop my game:

```
if ( parseInt(this.snakeHead.style.top) == fieldObj.h ||
         parseInt(this.snakeHead.style.left) == fieldObj.w ) {
        gameObj.stopGame();// stop game message
        clearTimeout(globalTimer);
    }
```

but it doesn't work -  stop game message appears, but animation continuing.

here all my code:

```
// field object
var globalTimer;
var fieldObj = {
  field: document.getElementById( "field" ),
  w: 480,
  h: 580
},
gameObj = {
  pastCoord: [],
  getRandomCoord: function( num ) { // 20 is width of one body segment
    return  Math.round( Math.floor(( Math.random() * num)) / 20 ) * 20;
  },
  createSnakeTarget: function() {
  var t = document.createElement( "div" );
      t.id = "snake-target";
      t.style.top = this.getRandomCoord( fieldObj.h ) + "px";
      t.style.left = this.getRandomCoord( fieldObj.w ) + "px";

      fieldObj.field.appendChild( t );
  },
  stopGame: function() {
    var stopMessage = document.createElement("div");
        stopMessage.className = "stop-message";
        stopMessage.style.background = "white";

        fieldObj.field.appendChild( stopMessage );
        //TODO: write message to stopGame
  }
};

gameObj.createSnakeTarget();

// snake object
snakeObj = {
  snakeHead: document.getElementById("head"),
  snakeBody: document.getElementsByClassName( "snake-body" ),// there must be one element
  p: {
    x: 0, // position x 
    y: 0  // position y
  },
  v: {
    x: 20, // velocity ( one loop move one unit of snake body)
    y: 20
  },
  keys: {
    up: null,
    l: null,
    r: null,
    down: null
  },
  stepInSnakeBody: 0,// go through snakeBody
  stepInPastCoord: 0,// go through pastCoord
  addBodySegment: function() {
    var seg = document.createElement( "div" );
          seg.className = "snake-body";
          fieldObj.field.appendChild( seg );

          seg.style.top = this.p.x + "px";// receive current position
          seg.style.left = this.p.y + "px";

  },
  update: function() {
    var snakeTarget = document.getElementById("snake-target");

    if ( this.keys.down ) {
       this.p.x += this.v.x;
    } else if ( this.keys.up ) {
       this.p.x -= this.v.x;
    } else if ( this.keys.r ) {
       this.p.y += this.v.y;
    }else if ( this.keys.l ) {
       this.p.y -= this.v.y;
    }
    this.snakeHead.style.top = this.p.x + "px";
    this.snakeHead.style.left = this.p.y + "px";

    gameObj.pastCoord.push([this.p.x, this.p.y]);// create and push coord of snake head

    //every step index in snakeBody receive coords from pastCoord
    this.snakeBody[this.stepInSnakeBody].style.top = gameObj.pastCoord[this.stepInPastCoord][0] + "px";
    this.snakeBody[this.stepInSnakeBody].style.left = gameObj.pastCoord[this.stepInPastCoord][1] + "px";

    this.stepInSnakeBody++; // increment index every step
    this.stepInPastCoord++;
    if ( this.stepInSnakeBody === this.snakeBody.length ) {
      this.stepInSnakeBody = 0; // when stepInSnakeBody equal length of snake go to zero
                                //and apply coords
    }
    // detect collision with target
    if ( this.snakeHead.style.top === snakeTarget.style.top &&
         this.snakeHead.style.left === snakeTarget.style.left ) {
        fieldObj.field.removeChild( snakeTarget );
        gameObj.createSnakeTarget();
        snakeObj.addBodySegment();
    }
    if ( parseInt(this.snakeHead.style.top) == fieldObj.h ||
         parseInt(this.snakeHead.style.left) == fieldObj.w ) {
        gameObj.stopGame();
        clearTimeout(globalTimer);
    }
  }
};

// Crome works only with keydown and keyup
window.addEventListener('keydown', function() {
// before changing direction you have to put previous direction to false
  if ( event.keyCode == 38 ) {
      snakeObj.keys.up = true;
      snakeObj.keys.down = false;
  } else if ( event.keyCode == 40 ) {
      snakeObj.keys.down = true;
      snakeObj.keys.up = false;
  } else if ( event.keyCode == 39 ) {
      snakeObj.keys.r = true;
      snakeObj.keys.up = false;
      snakeObj.keys.down = false;
  } else if ( event.keyCode == 37 ) {
      snakeObj.keys.l = true;
      snakeObj.keys.r = false;
      snakeObj.keys.up = false;
      snakeObj.keys.down = false;
  }
}, false);
//TODO: add event hendler to click to some button

window.addEventListener( "load", function gameLoop() {
  globalTimer = setTimeout( function() {
    snakeObj.update();
    requestAnimationFrame( gameLoop );
  }, 100 );
 });
```

here is codepen (works in CHROME only ) http://codepen.io/Kuzyo/pen/pamzC 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: why... are you using an animation frame within a timer?

Comment: wanted to slow a little animation http://codetheory.in/controlling-the-frame-rate-with-requestanimationframe/

Comment: http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Comment: Thanks @Andreas I read this article already, but don't understood what I have to do to cancel stop animation if I used setTimeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `cancelAnimationFrame`.

However you need to make sure you call `requestAnimationFrame` *before* `update`. Currently you're calling `stopGame`, but then after `stopGame`/`update` finishes, `requestAnimationFrame` schedules another loop so even if your `stopGame` calls `cancelAnimationFrame` it will not stop the animation.

An alternative is to use a boolean flag that you check in  your `gameLoop` function.

Comment: Thanks @emou help your second variant if ( stopAnim === true ) {
        cancelAnimationFrame( globalAnim );
    }

Comment: Not sure where you're calling that but I suspect `cancelAnimationFrame` is not needed. You can probably not request it at all if the game was stopped in the last update: `if(!gameObj.stopped) { requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop); }`